# Revoke Google Access Token with MFC

Tags: mfc, google-oauth

I have seen a few questions on this but they are not quite in my scenario. Unless I missed something.

This is how I revoke Google Access:

```
bool CCalendarSettingsGooglePage::RevokeGoogleAccess()
{
    CInternetSession    iSession;
    CHttpFile           *pWebFile = nullptr;
    CWaitCursor         wait;
    TCHAR               szError[_MAX_PATH];
    DWORD               dwStatusCode;
    CString             strError, strToken, strRevokeURL;

    if (m_strGoogleToken == _T(""))
        return true;

    strRevokeURL.Format(_T("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=%s"), (LPCTSTR)m_strGoogleToken);

    // ask user to go online
    if (InternetGoOnline((LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)strRevokeURL, GetSafeHwnd(), 0))
    {
        TRY
        {
            // our session should already be open
            // try to open up internet session to my URL
            // AJT v10.4.0 Use flag INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD
            pWebFile = (CHttpFile*)iSession.OpenURL(strRevokeURL, 1,
            INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_BINARY |
            INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD);

            if (pWebFile != nullptr)
            {
                if (pWebFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwStatusCode))
                {
                    if (dwStatusCode == 200) // OK!
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // There was a problem!
                        strError.Format(_T("Revoke error: %lu"), dwStatusCode);
                        AfxMessageBox(strError, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AfxMessageBox(_T("Revoke error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            }
        }
            CATCH(CException, e)
        {
            e->GetErrorMessage(szError, _MAX_PATH);
            AfxMessageBox(szError, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }
        END_CATCH

        // Tidy up
        if (pWebFile != nullptr)
        {
            pWebFile->Close();
            delete pWebFile;
        }
        iSession.Close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

My problem is that this approach does not always works. I find that a user has to actually go into their Google Account online, locate their apps, and manually revoke it.

Is there a more robust way to support revoking of an access token?

Comment: Actually, what token are you talking about? If the OAuth token expires or is revoked, the app will still remain in Google App settings.

Comment: My application has a Authenticate button. Shows the consent screen for my app. Then it lists their calendars. The token gets stored for later authentication. So they don't constantly get asked. But they should be able to revoke that authorisation so that the token won't work anymore. Removing the actual app from the settings is a bonus.

Comment: `dwStatusCode` 400 means success, it just indicates the token is already invalid. You should change the error check to `if (dwStatusCode == 200 || dwStatusCode == 400) return true; ...`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani OK. Are you saying I can use my existing code with changes? Or should I follow your answer? Also, if I make changes to the scopes used by my app, I assume the app needs to be removed from their account or would authorization attempt automatically ask for consent again?

Comment: This is a lot of guessing on my part. I think some of your users report seeing the error message `"Revoke error: 400"` from the code shown above, and they complain. Or maybe your program continues using an expired token. So if you change the error condition the problem should go away. Maybe there are additional problems if you are requesting refresh tokens. Run more tests from your own computer to try duplicate the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl` option to revoke token according to [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer):

```
curl -H "Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```

So your method should be okay. Maybe the token is already invalid and Google tells you that it doesn't know what to do with the request (the token may have a short life span)

OAuth usually expects `"POST"` method instead of `"GET"`. You can try the `"POST"` method instead. In MFC it would be as follows:

```
DWORD flag = INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE |
    INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID;

CStringW header;
CStringA query;

{
    CStringW queryW;
    queryW.Format(L"token=%s", token);
    query = CW2A(queryW, CP_UTF8);
}

header.Format(L"\
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\
Content-length: %d\r\n\
Connection: Close\r\n\
\r\n", query.GetLength());

CInternetSession session;
CHttpConnection *connection = session.GetHttpConnection(L"accounts.google.com", 
    (INTERNET_PORT)INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT);
if(connection)
{
    CHttpFile *file = connection->OpenRequest(L"POST", 
        L"o/oauth2/revoke", L"http://localhost", 1, NULL, NULL, flag);
    if(file)
    {
        if(file->SendRequest(header, 
            query.GetBuffer(), query.GetLength()))
        {
            DWORD dwRet;
            if (file->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwRet))
            {
                if (dwRet == 200 || dwRet == 400)
                {
                    //success!
                }
            }
        }
        delete file;
    }
    delete connection;
}
```

Above code uses Unicode version, it has to convert UTF-16 `query` to UTF-8...

Comment: What is the value for `flag`?

Comment: I added the flag. I was going to delete this post because I am not sure if there is anything wrong with your own GET method. You can also add `file->QueryInfoStatusCode` if you use this method.

Comment: Thanks. Trying now. Also, the page you showed me states for **400**: *For error conditions, a status code 400 is returned along with an error code.*

Comment: Yours works. . I am just curious about your comment concerning 400 because it doesn't match the doc. Also, what surprised me was revoking the token and authenticating did not actually require me to authorise the application again. I guess that is because the app is still in my consented apps. So the user must actually delete the app manually. It can't be done programmatically?

Comment: Since `dwStatusCode` might be **400** how do we then get **the error code** as per the Google page you showed?

Comment: I edited the post for `QueryInfoStatusCode`. I don't know how to remove the program from Google app settings.

Comment: Thanks. But why are you **accepting** a code of **400** as success? The documents state that 400 specifically means an **error**. Please explain.

Comment: OK, so there docs seem wrong. It can return 400 too. Confusing. Maybe you are right about my old code after all but no worry. I use this way. Just wished the doc matched!